# Why I am not able to perform group by operation for multiple groups on a solr collection

Tags: solr, solr4, solrcloud

I have 4 columns in Solr collection.
date,latitude,longitude,gpsdt.
And I want to perform a group by operation on three columns(data,latitude,longitude) and I have to find min and max value of gpsdt for each group.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In Solr you have to do this with Pivot Faceting and Stats. It will result in a query like

```
...&facet=true&facet.pivot={!stats=piv1}data,latitude,longitude&stats=true&stats.field={!tag=piv1}gpsdt
```

There is a good example in Solr Reference Guide. See [Combining Stats Component With Pivots](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_1/faceting.html#combining-stats-component-with-pivots)

Comment: Thanks ...When I issue this query on solr(separate db)  then it is working. But when I am accessing cassandra data through Solr query(I am using DSE) then it returns nothing.
And it is giving some error related UserCacheField.
So How to enable UserCacheField in a solr query?